# Developing windows phone Apps using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, titanium-mobile

I want to develop windows phone app using **Javascript and HTML**. As I'm currently working using the Appcelerator Titanium for developing iOS and Android Apps. I'm familiar with Javascript. Are there any Frameworks/Studios that uses Javascript for Windows phone App development.

Please share your Ideas.

Thanks

Comment: yes there is phonegap. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-7_index.md.html go with links

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 8.1 supports creation of JavaScript/HTML apps. Here's a tutorial that shows how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn631759.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no nice way to do this.

Windows 8/8.1 (and Win RT)-Apps can be done in different ways. For WP8 all you could do is open a fullscreen-browser and let your it load different HTML-sites..
But I don't think this will perform as well as c#/vb/c++-apps do.